# Failed to resolve github library

Tags: android, gradle, build, dependencies

I have a problem, I want to import [this library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3390#!description) into my project but Ive got gradle error:

> Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.android-cjj:JJSearchViewAnim:55291efd77
>    
>   Error:Failed to resolve: annotationProcessor
>   Open File

My gradle :

```
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'me.everything:providers-android:1.0.1'
 compile 'com.github.android-cjj:JJSearchViewAnim:55291efd77'
}
```

Maybe the dependency link is corrupted ? I took it from [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3390#!package)

Comment: I tried it from [Here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3390#!package) not working . Use it as library project .

Comment: Posting from mobile, so keeping it short. Try putting this in your grade build file 'compile com.github.android-cjj:JJSearchViewAnim:55291ef'